# How to create alerting policy on free disk space, only on root filesystem

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-stackdriver

I wanted to create a Alerting Policy in Stackdriver on "Volume Free Space" to get warned if the disk is almost full. So I used the Metric Threshold alert. However when I enable this check I get warnings straight away for a couple small partitions that are also on that machine. It seems I cannot limit it to only the main device.

A warning looks like this:

> Disk usage for server-website website with metric labels {device=tmpfs state===free} is below the threshold of 5368709120 with a value of 170569728.

Can I prevent alerts for these partitions (like `tmpfs`) or can I completely exclude these partitions from being reported to Stackdriver at all? It seems the Stackdriver agent automatically generates the `collectd` config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the alerting policy you need to select "Volume Usage (agent)" as a metric, which will show you Sub Resources and let you choose the partition you need.

Comment: The allows you to specify the threshold in relative numbers instead of absolute, but it works.